# EInsufficientRTTI exception with message 'Insufficient RTTi available to support this operation'

Tags: delphi, rtti, delphi-10.1-berlin

Trying to convert an object to JSON at run time, I'm getting insufficient RTTI Error.
The object is:

```
{$M+}
{$TYPEINFO ON}
{$METHODINFO ON}
{$RTTI EXPLICIT METHODS([vcPublic, vcPublished]) PROPERTIES([vcPublic, vcPublished])}

TMyPacket = class(TObject)
  Private
    FID: TGUID;
    FToIP: string;
    FToPort: integer;
    FSent: boolean;
    FSentAt: TDateTime;
    FAck: boolean;
    FTimeOut: Cardinal;
    FDataToSendSize: UINT64;
    FDataToSend: AnsiString;
  public
    constructor create;
    destructor free;
  published
    property ID: TGUID read FID write FID;
    property ToIP: string read FToIP write FToIP;
    property ToPort: integer read FToPort write FToPort;
    property Sent: boolean read FSent write FSent;
    property SentAt: TDateTime read FSentAt write FSentAt;
    property Ack: boolean read FAck write FAck;
    property TimeOut: Cardinal read FTimeOut write FTimeOut;
    property DataToSend: AnsiString read FDataToSend write FDataToSend;
  end;
```

later in the code:

```
var fpacket: TMYPacket;
begin     
fpacket := TVWTCPPacket.create;
//assign value to class properties
memo1.Lines.Text := TJson.ObjectToJsonString(fpacket); //throws error
```

and getting the error on JSON conversion.
Does anyone have any idea on whats going wrong with Delphi Berlin 10.1?
I do remember some RTTI issues on XE2 but not sure what is happening above is related to Delphi old bug or not.

Comment: As pointed out correctly by Stefan and Arnaud below the problem was with GUID direct serialization. However changing the field type with in the class did not work on my case. So I did intercept the GUID convertor which could be found below and it works perfectly. Thanks a lot guys.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Go into `System.Rtti` and put a breakpoint into `TRttiField.GetValue` at the line `if ft = nil then` and put a breakpoint condition `ft = nil` (if you would put the breakpoint in the next line you would not be able to see what the Name of the field was because of optimization).

When your debugger stops there you can inspect `Self.Name` (Ctrl+F7) and it will tell you `D4` which is the fourth field of your TGuid. This is because JsonReflect recursively serializes records by serializing their fields. Because `D4` is declared as `array[0..7] of Byte` it does not contain type info ([see also](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34747007/getting-type-of-record-field-with-rtti-fails-for-static-arrays)).

To solve this create your own type interceptor for `TGUID`:

```
type
  TGuidInterceptor = class(TJSONInterceptor)
  public
    function StringConverter(Data: TObject; Field: string): string; override;
    procedure StringReverter(Data: TObject; Field: string; Arg: string); override;
  end;

function TGuidInterceptor.StringConverter(Data: TObject;
  Field: string): string;
var
  ctx: TRttiContext;
begin
  Result := ctx.GetType(Data.ClassInfo).GetField(Field).GetValue(Data).AsType<TGuid>.ToString;
end;

procedure TGuidInterceptor.StringReverter(Data: TObject; Field, Arg: string);
var
  ctx: TRttiContext;
begin
  ctx.GetType(Data.ClassInfo).GetField(Field).SetValue(Data, TValue.From(TGuid.Create(Arg)));
end;
```

and mark the field accordingly:

```
[JsonReflect(ctString, rtString, TGuidInterceptor)]
FID: TGUID;
```

Comment: This works great, just one note: it only works if you use the unit Data.DBXJSONReflect and not the unit REST.JSONReflect, to use the JsonReflect custom attribute. Had me bang my head on desk for a while.

Answer (score 0):

There is no RTTI generated for `TGUID` kind of fields.

So in order to serialize your class, you may just use getter/setter functions, which set a string property.

Something like:

```
TMyPacket = class(TObject)
  Private
    FIDValue: TGUID;
    FToIP: string;
    FToPort: integer;
    FSent: boolean;
    FSentAt: TDateTime;
    FAck: boolean;
    FTimeOut: Cardinal;
    FDataToSendSize: UINT64;
    FDataToSend: AnsiString;
    procedure SetID(const value: string);
    function GetID: string;
  public
    constructor create;
    destructor free;
    property IDValue: TGUID read FID write FID;
  published
    property ID: string read GetID write SetID;
    property ToIP: string read FToIP write FToIP;
    property ToPort: integer read FToPort write FToPort
  ...

procedure TMyPacket.SetID(const value: string);
begin
  fIDValue := StringToGUID(value);
end;

function TMyPacket.GetID: string;
begin
  result := GUIDToString(fIDValue);
end;
```

Then serialization should work, with a `"ID":` string field, and you will get the `TGUID` value in the `IVValue` public property.

Comment: I think this will not work because JsonReflect operates on the fields.

Comment: If it is the case, JsonReflect is just disapointing. Our serialization in mORMot does support directly the TGUID published fields by the way.

Comment: I would have expected that as well from JsonReflect for built-in types such as TGUID.

Comment: Your TJSONInterceptor solution is only way to go, then... ;)

Answer (score 0):

check if this lines exists in the dpr file, if it exists you have to delete it

```
{$IFOPT D-}{$WEAKLINKRTTI ON}{$ENDIF}
{$RTTI EXPLICIT METHODS([]) PROPERTIES([]) FIELDS([])}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).